# Couchbase document size limit

Tags: couchbase

I Saw that Couchbase doucment size limit is 20mb.

So if I have a user and the user has 1000 products maybe and the document size is now larger than 20mb how I handle this Situation ?

Comment: You should have those 1000 products in their own product documents, i.e. each product should have one document. 
Then you should reference the 1000 products in the users documents using the product ID

Comment: That's one way, another way is that you could split up the list of products into multiple document "pages". I guess it depends on how you plan to access them. I would assume that you don't need to query all 1000 products at once, so keeping them in their own documents (as @Siraf suggested) should be fine. If you *do* need to access them *all* on a regular basis, consolidating them into pages might be faster (although slightly more complex to develop)